# How to report progress by percentages in backgroundworker dowork event?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            var filesl = GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.*").ToList();
            for(int i = 0; i < filesl.Count; i++)
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filesl[i]);
                if (File.Exists(info.FullName))
                {
                    dic.Add(filesl[i], info.Length);
                }
                int progress = (int)(((float)(i + 1) / filesl.Count) * 100);
                worker.ReportProgress(progress, filesl[i]);

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
```

it's reporting fine the items in the list in the worker.ReportProgress but the variable int progress value is all the time 0. in this case there are almost 40000 files in filesl.

Comment: Your variable is is the loop every time it will be reset.  You need it outside of the loop.  Also you need to call it like progress += i+1/filesl.count*100 or similar.

Comment: Did you test it with values of `i` greater than 400? With 40k files in total, you'll see 1% only after 400 files are processed.

Comment: The long sleep makes this loop take over an hour with 40,000 files.  You'd have to wait for over 40 seconds to see a non-zero value, surely you didn't wait that long.

Comment: @HansPassant right, i changed the Sleep value to 1 millisecond and it's working fine. if i'm not wrong now it will increase the progressBar each 7 seconds. i counted the progressBar get updating each 7 seconds. can i do it faster ? i mean that the Sleep will be les then 1 millisecond or 1 millisecond is good enough ?

Comment: @SherylLarson - Try this: `int progress = 100 * (i + 1) / filesl.Count;`. If you do the `100 *` first then the integer math works.

Comment: @SherylLarson - FYI, Windows can't sleep less than 16.5ms. Even if you  do `Sleep(1)` it's actually like `Sleep(16.5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly correct. Due to the amount of files the variable will return "0" (0%) until it reaches at least 400 files, which then the calculation would return "1" (1%). If you do this calculation more precisely (without converting to INT) you will see that the percentage is fractional, 0.005%, 0.0075%...

Comment: ReportProgress not getting float.  if i'm not converting it to int first then it will give error cant convert from float to int.

Comment: The conversion is correct if you need the value to be an integer. However, as you need an integer value you will have the "0" for a long time in the execution, but this "0" will change as the execution goes on.

to show it more accurately you would have to do it this way, showing the fractional percentage.

float progress = (((float)(i+1) / filesl.Count) * 100);